# show record view/edit form from quick action component

Tags: slds, modal, lightning-data-service, lds

I am trying to show a Record View/Edit forms in a modal from lightning quick action component. In this quickaction component I am using lightning data table to show list of records and beside the records there is a action to show details or edit the record. When I am clicking the show details lightning record form component is called but it is showing the fields in vertical manner and save cancel button is not present.

How can I add scroll to see the bottom elements or what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
style="overflow-y: auto !important;"
```

This was the solution to my problem. I was trying with different slds classes of scrollable but didnt work, neither in quick action component nor in record form child component